# What is explicit isomorphic map between $\Bbb R$ and $\text{Alt}^n(\Bbb R^n)$

Tags: multilinear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

We denote $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to be an open set.

**Definition 1:** Let $\text{Alt}^p(\Bbb R^n)$ denote the set of all alternating multlinear functionals on $\Bbb R^n$.

**Definition 2:** Let $\Omega^p(V)$ denote the set of all differential $p-$forms where $\omega: V \subset \Bbb R^n \to \text{Alt}^p(\Bbb R^n) $

**Definition 3:** Let $C^\infty(V,\Bbb R)$ denote the set of all smooth maps from $V$ to $\Bbb R.$

I am reading [notes (prob 3.1)](http://www.brynmawr.edu/physics/DJCross/docs/cohomology/hw3.pdf)  that say that $\Omega^2(\Bbb R^2) \cong C^\infty (V, \Bbb R)$ in the following manner. Don't worry, this small part of the question only requires a good understanding of linear algebra to explain to me.

> For any $\tau \in \text{Alt}^3(\Bbb R^3)$, $\tau = \tilde{\tau} e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3$ where $\tilde{\tau} \in \Bbb R.$ So we regard an $\omega \in \Omega^3(V)$ as a smooth map $\omega : V \to \text{Alt}^3(\Bbb R^3)\cong \Bbb R$, that is a smooth function on $V$.

So what I am not understanding is that, what is the isomorphism map between $\text{Alt}^3(\Bbb R^3)\cong \Bbb R$? All I see is that they have the same dimension, so isomorphism exists. What is the point of introducing $\tau = \tilde{\tau}e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3$?. He repeats the same thing again for $\text{Alt}^2(\Bbb R^2)\cong \Bbb R$ later.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I've thought of that too, but why is that one to one and onto? I know each $e^i$ send it to the determinant of the Kroneckor delta, but I can't see how this is one to one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes that is true. I only wrote that out of habit when I talk about isomoprhisms.

Comment: I mean inside the determinant, but the value be either $0$ or $1$ must come from some input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isomorphism between the two spaces is more or less obvious. If $V$ is a real vector space with basis $e_1,\ldots ,e_k$, then the map
$$
\Phi\colon Alt^k(V)\rightarrow V, \; \omega\mapsto \omega(e_1,\ldots ,e_k)
$$
is a linear isomorphism. For a proof, see for example Corollary $B.2.12$ [here](http://math-www.upb.de/user/hilgert/static/Lehrveranstaltungen/multilinear_algebra.pdf).

Comment: Would you mind elaborating the part where he showed it is injective? All I see is that he set $\phi(\omega) = 0$ and so $\omega(v_1, \dots, v_k) = 0.$ I am guessing this means $\nul \phi = \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: He starts with $\Phi(\omega)=0$ and shows $\omega=0$ by Proposition $B.2.11$. Hence $\Phi$ is injective.